# Transfer of GIF File from Photoshop to phone

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I export a .GIF file in PC, it works fine on Internet Explorer as soon as I try to transfer it on WhatsApp either it appears as an image.

For simplifying the issue I took the GIF file on my Gmail account & downloaded it on phone & shared it on WhatsApp now the .GIF file is running but all the time frame of the GIF file has been disturbed, it is not playing the required delays which I have made in the original file.

Please help out

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. View the GIF in the browser on your phone instead.  If it works properly, then the problem is with WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a lot of guidelines/restrictions for sharing and exporting gifs. If you are tied to WhatsApp, I'd suggest uploading the gif to giphy/imgur then sending a link. If you're flexible, I've found dropbox and other cloud file sharing apps to be much more streamlined for transferring graphics files to my phone.